# mysqli update the date not working

Tags: php, mysqli

I need to update the date and it just don't work, I'm getting sick of this crap!
I tryed:

```
mysqli_query($con, "UPDATE nachrichten SET update = CURDATE() WHERE file = '$msgfile'");
mysqli_query($con, "UPDATE nachrichten SET update = 'CURDATE()' WHERE file = '$msgfile'");
mysqli_query($con, "UPDATE nachrichten SET update = '2014-09-11'  WHERE file = '$msgfile'");
mysqli_query($con, "UPDATE nachrichten SET update = 2014-09-11  WHERE file = '$msgfile'");
```

And much more NON of this s*** is working whats the problem with that? The field type is date and the connection etc works fine I tested other field updates but only the date BS isn't working it's always 0000-00-00

Comment: Guessing is pointless. Try in a direct SQL interface, once you have it sorted, use it. And then add in proper error reporting in the PHP so at least an error message is reported.. (and also, use placeholders as it could very trivially be made to "not work" based on a value of $msgfile that makes the literal invalid)

Comment: Thats not easy because I use AJAX for this PHP file

Comment: It doesn't matter. Guessing is pointless. What *error* occurs? What *values* were used?

Comment: I can't return error report from AJAX, what do you mean by what values?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The field `update` keyword and the SQL keyword `UPDATE` conflicted here. yes of course you can see the errors from ajax using the `firebug` mozilla plugin.

This is works for me to separate **update** keyword from SQL.

```
mysqli_query($con, "UPDATE nachrichten SET `update` = 2014-09-11  WHERE file = '$msgfile'");
```

Comment: omg that was it thanks!! I was rly getting sick about that